# Solving the recurrence T(n) = 2T(sqrt(n))+log2n

Tags: math, big-o, recurrence

I would like to solve the following recurrence relation:

T(n) = 2T(sqrt(n))+log2n

Unfortunately, neither the master theorem nor the akra-bazzi-method can be applied in this case. I guess that the solution must be O(log log n) but I am not sure how to prove this.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 4):

Make the substitution:

[image]

Then the recurrence becomes:

[image]

We'll assume here that `log` is base 2, WLOG.

[image]

There are `log(m)` of these terms (ignoring off-by-one etc.), so:

- The `m` terms sum to `m log(m)`
- The "constant" terms are a geometric series, and sum to

[image]

(... so we ignore it)

Thus the overall complexity is:

[image]